# DevOps description field image download / Save file

Tags: c#, image, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Since we have moved to Dev Ops my application fails to download the images that are in any field stored in a work item.

I have an image URL that has already been stripped out of the description files via a regular expression.

If I take this link and paste it in to a browser then it returns the images (so the url is valid)

The issue is that within the call to download the image we dont have any authentication credentials and its trying to return me to a login page.

I do authenticate with the dev ops server within my application and it caches these.

```
readonly VssCredentials creds = new VssClientCredentials();
```

I have tried to use a webclient to make the call but you cant cast the VSScredentuals to system.net credentials

this used to work before

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
          byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(src);

          using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data))
          {
                using (var yourImage = Image.FromStream(mem))
                {
                 // If you want it as Png
                 yourImage.Save(@"c:\temp\path_to_your_file.png", ImageFormat.Png);

                  // If you want it as Jpeg
                  yourImage.Save(@"c:\temp\path_to_your_file.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
          }
}
```

I have tried also using

```
using (var client = new TfvcHttpClient(new Uri(src), creds))
{
        var itemRequestData = Create(src);
}

private static TfvcItemRequestData Create(string folderPath)
{
  return new TfvcItemRequestData
  {
    IncludeContentMetadata = true,
    IncludeLinks = true,
    ItemDescriptors =
          new[]
          {
                    new TfvcItemDescriptor
                    {
                        Path = folderPath,
                        RecursionLevel = VersionControlRecursionType.Full
                    }
          }
  };
}
```

But how do i then write the itemRequestData to a file?

Or am i going about this the wrong way?

thanks

Comment: Hi Alan, I don't see you passing creds to the regular webclient, maybe it's just what you pasted, but you should pass the creds at Client creation or as a property before you make the call to download.  You can also try and download with the current user credentials, if he has access to TFS the regular webclient download should work fine.

Comment: This is the trouble im having,My application does hold the credential for the TFS server in VssCredentials object.

The web client code is the old method.
However when trying to resolve this issue the webclient object will not accept the the VssCredentials object as a parameter.

So how to a cast it to a system.net credential object??

we all have access to the TFS server, and if the authentication is stale we are asked to authenticate on app startup (in to the VssCredentials). 

As it stands the system (IE) cached credentials are not being used when I try and use a webclient object

Comment: May I know which tfs version do you use? If convenient, could you please share us a simple sample(delete the personal info and replace PAT with xxx) to reproduce the issue. We want to have a test in our side to better troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: @AlanRampton try with the Credentials property see here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.credentials?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_WebClient_Credentials

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Token);
    byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(src);

    // ....      
}
```

Where **base64Token** is your Personal Access Token converted to base64 with a ":" at the start.

For example if your token is *abcdefg* you need to convert *:abcdefg* to base64 and use it as the authorization token.